# How to prevent xss from java api side

Tags: java, api, xss

I have REST API with Java Springboot 2.1.5.RELEASE and need to prevent every controller to check first the `RequestBody` contain XSS or not. if yes I want to return like `BadRequest`. The App only for API no `HTML, JSP and etc`

Here is sample my controller

```
 @PostMapping("/test1")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseModel> process(@Valid @RequestBody Student request)
```

I've tried with some library to check `Student` to Json and clean the XSS like `https://github.com/OWASP/json-sanitizer/` and etc

but still, doesn't work

and Already check https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html

but still not found about implement in java api

I expect every request to API reject/return 400(BadRequest) 
The validation can be on `Controller`, `Filter`, `Interceptor` or `Spring Security`

Comment: Huh? How does JSON "contain XSS"?

Comment: i mean like this {"data":"<script>shshsh</script>%3cDIV%20STYLE%3d%22background-image%3a%5c0075%5c0072%5c006C%5c0028'%5c006a%5c0061%5c0076%5c0061%5c0073%5c0063%5c0072%5c0069%5c0070%5c0074%5c003a%5c0061%5c006c%5c0065%5c0072%5c0074%5c0028%2e1027%5c0058%2e1053%5c0053%5c0027%5c0029'%5c0029%22%3e"}

Comment: or how i can sanitize from xss for string of json

Comment: Could you please explain more : "This still doesn't work" ? Did you do some pentesting to said this ? How did you use json sanitizer (post code please...)

Comment: I mean, how we know The JSON contain XXS with library like esapi or json-sanitizer with json like this : {
  "uuid": "1846e86c-5b9f-40a0-bc33-aa58b57990a8",
  "data1": "<script>test</script>",
  "data2": "javascript:test",
  "data3": "haloha"
}